# Get column width if it is set to "2*" to Binding in xaml WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, wpf-animation, actualwidth

I have StackPanel in the third column of Grid "MainGrid". It's(third column) width set to "2*".

I want to hide StackPanel using margin and then use slide animation to show it.

So i need to set **Margin** of StackPanel to Column[2] **Width**, but how can i get it?
I'm trying this:

```
Margin="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ColumnDefinitions[2].ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource marginConverter}}
```

So, i add breakpoint to converter in code-behind and it always get 0.

I've tried to use **MainGrid**.ActualWidth insted of **Column[2]** ActualWidth and it send to converter at first **zero**, then it's **actual width**.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your debug output window saying `Cannot find source for binding ...`?

Comment: no, it send to to converter "0"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `ColumnDefinition.ActualWidth` is not a dependency property, that means it will not report the update. A quick solution is write a new class inherit from `ColumnDefinition` and notify `ActualWidth` is changed everytime the parent `Grid` had updated its layout. And instead of `ColumnDefinition`, use this class in xaml.

```
public class MyColumnDefinition : ColumnDefinition, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MyColumnDefinition() : base() { }

    protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInitialized(e);

        ((Grid)Parent).LayoutUpdated += MyColumnDefinition_LayoutUpdated;
    }

    private void MyColumnDefinition_LayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ActualWidth"));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```